# Figure out how much time it takes to do an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, timer

I am attempting to figure how long it takes to do an AJAX request, when a button is clicked so far I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#start').click(function() {
        start_timer();
        var record = $.ajax({url: "ajax.php?getSensor="+devid, async: false }).responseText;
        $("textarea#recordTextbox").val($('textarea#recordTextbox').val()+record+"\n");
        stoptimer();
    }); 
});
```

And my timer functions look like this:

```
function start_timer() {
     display();
}
function stoptimer() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = 0;
}
function display(){
  if (millisec>=9){
     millisec=0
     seconds+=1
  }
  else
     millisec+=1
     $("#time").html(seconds + "." + millisec);
     timer = setTimeout("display()",100);
  }
```

The AJAX request is sent properly but the timer reads 0.1 seconds everytime, I know that it takes longer than this because the page hangs for at least 3 seconds. For some reason the timer does not run when its off doing its AJAX deal.

Any advice would help, thanks!

Comment: I know this is a work-around to what you're trying to accomplish, but in Google Chrome, you can view response times by pressing `CTRL-SHIFT-J` and viewing the console. That, or you can use the FireBug plugin for FireFox or Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get this timer to work, so I used Date().getTime() like this:

```
    var start_time = new Date().getTime();       
    $.ajax({url: "ajax.php?getSensor="+devid, async: false, success: function(data){ 
        $("textarea#recordTextbox").val($('textarea#recordTextbox').val()+data+"\n");
        request_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time; 
    }});
    $("#time").html(request_time/1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easier with an asynchronous request as such:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#start').click(function() {
        start_timer();
        $.ajax({url: "ajax.php?getSensor="+devid, async: false, success: function(data){ 
            $("textarea#recordTextbox").val($('textarea#recordTextbox').val()+data+"\n");
            stoptimer(); 
        }});
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Yes, the reason that the timer in the OP's post is not working is because it is not being stopped in the AJAX callback.

Comment: So for some reason it's still showing .1 of a second each time when chrome's dev tools is showing ~2.5 seconds for each request, maybe my timer code is screwed up? Also, you said I could use an asynchronous request but we still have async: false in the code, is this on purpose? Sorry kinda new to this

Comment: Well thank you for your code, but this doesn't work :/ When I comment out stoptimer completely, the timer halts at 0.1 seconds until the ajax request has finished and then continues to ascend

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this to aid development, use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/network).

Comment: It's for a web app that I'm making, but thanks for the suggestion, firebug is very useful

Comment: the resources tab of the webkit (safari/chrome) inspector works too.

Comment: Yes I've seen they have made some improvements to how you can now alter css on the fly which wasn't there before

Answer (score 0):

**Just run YSlow over it.**

For a general purpose approach to determining what's wrong with your page loads and AJAX requests, then use the [YSlow addon for Firefox](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/).

It'll show you stuff that you've never even dreamed of that's slowing your code down.